# Autofill Excel columns but updating formulas by increments

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Bascially I have the below function:

[image]

And I want to drag it so next cell is

[image]

Basically in the correlation formula, the inputs are increasing by 20 each time (roughly the amount of days the stock market is open in that month. Bonus points if I am able to set a soft increase when autofilling depending on month length but for now increasing it by 20 each time I fill is enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use INDEX and some math:

```
=CORREL(INDEX(Data!B:B,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*20+21):INDEX(Data!B:B,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*20+40),INDEX(Data!E:E,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*20+21):INDEX(Data!E:E,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*20+40))
```